# Get string to array with multiple .each function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have two elements and will get strings inside. (and i use .each` function)

The problem is that the second array (after got string by `.each`), is replace the first one.

Sorry, if you don't understand, but try to look below...

```
$('div').each(function () {
    var data = [];
    $('li', this).each(function () {
        data.push($(this).text());
    });
    var data_length = data.length;
    $(this).children("code").html(data + "");
    $("code").click(function () {
        data.move(data_length - 1, 0);
        $(this).html(data + "");
    });
});

Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            this.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
    return this; // for testing purposes
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kdpN7/

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Your `.move(l - 1, 0)` can be written as `a.unshift(a.pop())` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the same reason you do `$(this).children('code')` you should also bind your click event with a scope.

The problem is, you're iterating over 2 divs (your `each`) which means you're binding `$('code')` twice.  The first time `code` is bound to click, it binds with the first data array (the 1's) and then it is bound a second time with (the 2's).  So it IS first doing your click code for the 1s and then immediately running it for the 2s, thus overwriting.  Change to `$(this).find("code")` (or `children`) and it works as expected.

http://jsfiddle.net/kdpN7/1/

Answer (score 1):

On this line:

```
$("code").click(function () { ...
```

This is telling to update all `code` with that information. You need to change it so it's specific to each div:

```
$(this).find("code").click(function () { ...
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kdpN7/2/